# Android customlistview crashes after scrolling repeatedly

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I made a listview with a custom layout but every time I scroll fast the app crashes with the following error in Logcat.

I haven't really tried anything yet since I'm still not familiar with Android.
I have tried adding `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` AND `android:largeHeap="true"` in to the `AndroidManifest.xml` but still nothing.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_switch_account,null);
            TextView first = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.full_name);
            ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture);

            Account account = accountList.get(position);
            first.setText(account.getName());
            byte[] imgs = account.getImage();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgs,0,imgs.length);
            img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
//            status.setText(account.getStatus());

        return convertView;
    }
}

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 3481968 byte allocation with 1143504 free bytes and 1116KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:622)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:645)
        at com.example.mgimoro.dietgo.AccountAdapter.getView(AccountAdapter.java:51)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2497)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1930)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:722)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:686)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5792)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3705)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:4221)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3991)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9480)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2662)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2304)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2318)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2318)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2318)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2318)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2318)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2318)
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:largeHeap="true"` in the application tag inside AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: yes i have tried that too but it still crashes

Comment: maybe your bitmap is very large, try loading bitmap asynchronously or use library like glide or picasso

Answer (score 1):

OutOfMemoryError is the most common problem occured in android while especially dealing with bitmaps. This error is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when an object cannot be allocated due to lack of memory space and also, the garbage collector cannot free some space.

As mentioned by Aleksey, you can add below entities in your manifest file android:hardwareAccelerated="false" , android:largeHeap="true" it will work for some environment's.

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

If you getting this error from emulator please VM Heap

[image]

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit that I already tried adding those but still it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to decode a large bitmap inside a ListView. Try to [DownSample](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) your bitmap or better yet use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or Picasso to do it for you.

**UPDATE:** You're still using `ListView` which is now been replaced by `RecyclerView`. `RecyclerView` is a better tool to display a list of items.
If you decided to stick to `ListView` you should implement the `ViewHolder` pattern to minimize view inflation thus improving the performance of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`. As it is more advance than `ListView`.

**Here is the official link:**
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Also try to use pagination concept in Your `RecyclerView`. In simple words first load portion of your data i.e. 1-10 items then load next data i.e. 11-20 items when user scroll through your list. Such process will increase your loading time and will decrease the memory load.